# Unable to delete over 400 contacts from Outlook using Office Interop

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop

I have this code to delete all contacts from Microsoft Outlook that have a specific user property:

```cs
public void PurgePTSContacts(ref long rlCount)
{
    int iLastPercent = 0;
    rlCount = 0;

    try
    {

        // Get the MAPI namespace object (not sure exactly what this is)
        Outlook.NameSpace MAPI = _OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
        if (MAPI != null)
        {
            // Now get the default Outlook Contacts folder
            Outlook.MAPIFolder oFolder = MAPI.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);
            if (oFolder != null)
            {
                // Ensure it is a calendar folder.  This test is not strictly required.
                if (oFolder.DefaultItemType == Outlook.OlItemType.olContactItem)
                {
                    // Get the collect of items from the calendar folder
                    Outlook.Items oFolderItems = oFolder.Items;
                    if (oFolderItems != null)
                    {
                        int iNumItems = oFolderItems.Count;

                        // Progress to do

                        int iItem = 0;
                        foreach (object oItem in oFolderItems)
                        {
                            iItem++;

                            if(oItem is Outlook.ContactItem )
                            {
                                Outlook.ContactItem oContact = (oItem as Outlook.ContactItem);

                                int iPercent = ((iNumItems - iItem) + 1) * 100 / iNumItems;
                                if (iPercent >= iLastPercent + 5 || iPercent == 100)
                                {
                                    iLastPercent = iPercent;
                                    // Show progress
                                }

                                Outlook.UserProperties oContactDetails = oContact.UserProperties;
                                if (oContactDetails != null)
                                {
                                    if (oContactDetails.Find("xxxxx") != null)
                                    {
                                        oContact.Delete();
                                        rlCount++;
                                    }
                                }

                                oContact = null;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

Now, what i don't understand is that when I import the contacts, there are 428. But when I delete the contacts, it only does just over 200. Then I have to repeatedly call my `PurgePTSContacts` method and it purges some more.

With each subsequent call less and less are purged until it is 0.

Why can't I purge all 400x in one function call?

Comment: What's the value of `oFolder.Items;` after stepping into the code? Also `if(oItem is Outlook.ContactItem )` are you sure they are all `Outlook.ContactItem`? IMHO there are many conditionals in your code, can you write to a log to confirm your conditions are doing what you want and actually need?

Comment: Off topic: you should invert all those `if` statements to avoid all that nesting. Your code has become a [pyramid of doom](https://imgur.com/FIq3lWx).

Comment: @LewsTherin Point taken. I have simplified my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use `foreach` when you are modifying the collection - use a down loop:

```
for (int i = FolderItems.Count; i >= 1; i--)
{
  object oItem = FolderItems[i];
  Outlook.ContactItem oContact = (oItem as Outlook.ContactItem);
  if (oContact  != null)
  {
    ...
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oContact);
  }
  Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oItem);
}
```

**UPDATE**. Per OP request, an example that shows how to delete all items in a folder using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) (I am its author):

```
RDOSession session = new RDOSession();
session.MAPIOBJECT = MAPI.MAPIOBJECT; //an instance of the Namespace object from your snippet above
RDOFolder rFolder = session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts); //or you can use RDOSession.GetFolderFromID if you already have an Outlook.MAPIFolder
rFoldder.EmptyFolder ();
```

If you want to only delete contacts (but not distribution lists), you can retreive their entry ids first using `RDOFolder.Items.MAPITable.ExecSQL("SELECT EntryID from Folder where MessageClass LIKE 'IPM.Contact%' ")` (ExecSQL returns an instance of the `ADODB.Recordset` COM object), use it to to build an array of entry ids, and pass it to `RDOFolder.Items.RemoveMultiple()`.

To create an instance of the [RDOSession](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm) object, you can also use the [RedemptionLoader](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/security.htm#redemptionloader) class if you don't want to register redemption.dll in the registry using regsvr32.exe (you can just place redemption.dll alongside your executable).

Comment: Thank you! I had no idea about this. I see you use `Marshal.ReleaseComObject(..);` Should I be using this for all of my objects?

Comment: It is good to always use ReleaseComObject with COM objects (as well as avoid multiple dot notation), but it is a must when looping over a large number of items - you can run out of RPC  channels in the online mode.

Comment: So I should add after the loop code: `Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oFolderItems); Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oFolder); Marshal.ReleaseComObject(MAPI);`

Comment: It won't hurt, but it is less critical than releasing the variables inside the loop.

Comment: And just for completeness sake, it is a lot faster to delete multiple items using Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi) or Redemption (any language) -it exposes RDOFolder.Items.RemoveMultiple and RDOFolder.EmptyFolder

Comment: I assume you mean this package? http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm Are you able to provide a C# example using this in your answer as an alternative? Can we deploy this with our applications?

Comment: Thanks. In my case I only want to delete contacts with a specific user property.

Comment: You can modify the SQL query appropriately - look at an existing contact with that property set with OutlookSpy (click IMessage button, select the property, look at the DASL edit box), use the DASL name (in double quotes) to add a query like ("propname"  IS NOT NULL) and ("propname" = 'some value')